# Fix "dynamic" query without throwing me the given error?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, express, sql-update

```
UPDATE dbo.Einkauf_Web_Upload 
SET
  ${
    updatedUpload.Menge !== null
      ? `Anzahl = ${`${updatedUpload.Menge}`},`
      : null
  },
  ${
    updatedUpload.ENummer !== null
      ? `ENummer = ${`'${updatedUpload.ENummer}'`}`
      : null
  }
 
  WHERE ...
```

This query is supposed to differentiate between updated values of the object `updatedUpload` which, initially, has all of its values set to null. If the value is not altered therefor not updated, the query must not affect the particular column. In its current state, the query throws this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'

And I know why; if you do not alter the Menge attribute, the query looks like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Einkauf_Web_Upload 
SET null, ENummer = "abc" 
WHERE ..
```

Is there a workaround to this? I am using NodeJs as my backend and thought of trying to make the column references dynamic via a mapped array which contains only the altered columns of `updatedUpload`.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: BTW- This is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  You should switch to a solution that uses parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for the injection advice, taking notes there. The post result is this: class: 15
code: "EREQUEST"
lineNumber: 3
name: "RequestError"
number: 156
originalError:
info:
class: 15
event: "errorMessage"
lineNumber: 3
message: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'."
name: "ERROR"
number: 156
procName: ""
serverName: "AZBUSQL001\\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: just replacing `: null` by `: ''` (empty string) would do?

Comment: @JorgeCampos brilliant, didnt think of this. works like a charm xd thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`SET null, ...` is invalid SQL syntax, you should skip the `null` at all. Furthermore, remember not to do the query if there is nothing to update as `SET WHERE ...` is also invalid syntax.

I would suggest something like:

```
let updates = [
    updatedUpload.Menge !== null ? `Anzahl = ${`${updatedUpload.Menge}`}` : null,
    updatedUpload.ENummer !== null ? `ENummer = ${`'${updatedUpload.ENummer}'`}` : null,
    // ... add here
]

// Filter out null updates
updates = updates.filter(u => !!u);
    
// Do query only if updates are avaliable
if (updates.length > 0) {
    const sql = `UPDATE dbo.Einkauf_Web_Upload SET ${updates.join(', ')} WHERE ...`;
    // ... execute
}
```

Comment: Instead of givin null i give back "", works like a charm. To prevent "empty" queries when there was no update, i will let the user only submit if he at least commited one change. Thank you nevertheless for taking your time

Comment: With your technique, you will still have a problem with the commas try to update `Menge` and not `ENummer` ;)